# React - Unable to retrieve latest value of a text field in a form

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, I have a text field within a form:

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
const handleUrlChange = useCallback((value) => setUrl(value), []);
```

And then the form itself

```
return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <FormLayout>

        <TextField
          value={url}
          label="Url"
          type="url"
          onChange={handleUrlChange}
        />
)
```

In the onSubmit method, on getting that URL value, it's always returning an empty string. I've checked the `value` when `setUrl` is called and value is definitely there.

```
const handleSubmit = useCallback(async (_event) => {

    console.log(url);

}, []);
```

I guess I miss understanding some fundamental hooks thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add the `url` variable in the `useCallback` inputs array :

```
const handleSubmit = useCallback(async (_event) => {
  console.log(url);
}, [url]);
```

With an empty array, the memoïzed function will never be re-created, so the `url` variable will always return the value of the first assignment (an empty string)

By the way, you need to put into the arrays all the variables used into the function that are declared outside of this function.

Comment: Thanks - that works! But I don't understand why - whats the `memoïze function`?

Comment: Also, does it mean that every one of mine form fields, need to be mentioned in that array?

Comment: plead read the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback to understand how useCallback works, you only need to put into the array the variables that are used in the function and that are not part of the inputs of the function (the variables declared outside of the function)